# What is the best practice for managing multiple password accounts in my app?

Tags: android, passwords

My Android app will fetch media from many different repositories on the Internet (DropBox, Instagram, Flickr, etc.). Each of these has different access APIs, and users will have different credentials on each.

Is there a recommended 'best practice' for handling multiple sets of credentials I can fetch from inside my app and match to the appropriate service?

If a user already has credentials stored locally for a particular service, I'd like to simply use it and not bug them (other than perhaps a one time permission to use it). If they don't then I need to prompt them for the data (name, pw etc.) that the API for that service requires in order to get access to its file store.

I have reviewed Smart Lock, Autofill and the like - but these seem geared to make it simple to log in to my app - not necessarily log in to other services FROM my app.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone tell me why my question was immediately downvoted after I submitted it? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Most of those services offer OAuth2 for authentication, and this is the recommended way to access them. With OAuth2 you won't need to store the passwords yourself, instead you get a token after the user logged on to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is good to use for authentication. It is possible to get a lot of information such as name mail, especially the user id information that you will need to use. user IDs are very useful for firebase authantication to be created with mail addresses. I also suggest Facebook's account kit service.